# How can I move "AMAZON PAY" button from shipping address to Payment Methods In one step checkout magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, amazon-payment

I want amazon pay button inside my payment method block where all the payments shows, How can i do that is anyone have an idea ???

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps and you get your result.

```
1) Go to stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment methods.

2) Go to Amazon Pay -> Advanced -> Frontend

3) Now change the dropdown(Show Amazon Pay in payment methods) value No to Yes.

4) Now Click on save config and you get result you want.
```